# Can we turn the "own text" color of chat down a few notches?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, chat

The new design has been implemented in chat. However the orange that is used for a user's own chat messages seems a little bit too bright.

Would it be possible to turn it down just a touch? I don't mind it standing out, but it's a bit too high contrast for me.

Comment: Funny. It _is pretty strong_ but a couple of us commented on how we liked it when it first showed up. My main complaint has been that everything was too washed out, chat being the one exception :)

Comment: @Caleb I like the contrast, I just think it might be *too high*

Comment: I like it too. And said so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the color is a bit strong, especially if you type a lot of messages at once. We'll tune it down some, to #f4e8cd. The change should be live within the next couple of hours.